# Add Custom Fields after a Managed Package is Released

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-field

Based on the following I understand that new custom fields of an existing custom object aren't available to users after Pushing a Managed Packaged

[Assigning Access to New Components and Fields](http://htps://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/push_upgrade_assigning_access.htm)

From the link one option it recommends to allow users access to new custom fields in a Managed Package is to create a new Permission Set which has access to the custom fields.  Then create a Post Install script that assigns users to the new Permission Set.  The users assigned to the new Permission Set should be those who have access to the component of the custom fields.

I created the new Permission Set and Post Install Script and it assign users to the Permission Set who have access to the Object of the new Custom Fields

I tested this is our Business Org and it worked!  When I deployed to a customer who has our Managed Package installed, the Permission Set was created in their Org but no one was assigned to it; not even Admins.

Any idea why the users who have access to the Custom Object didn't get assigned to the new Permission Set?

Answer (score 0):

Meaning that every time you will add a field you'll have to create new permission sets ?
Lol, after some time you would have dozens of PS, it would be hard to maintain, and messy :D

You can deliver a permission set for your managed package users ( or several, if you have different type of users), then everytime you add a new field, you can add rights to it in the existing permission set, then when you will push the upgrade, users already assigned to your managed permission set will automatically have access

If your package users prefer to not use your permission sets but profiles, or their own PS, you can just write in the release note the new fields that they have to grant rights in their custom profiles/PS

Comment: Thanks Nicolas!
Yes, plan to create new permission set for new fields..goal is 1,000  PSs :-).
Seriously, problem is package exists in 1,000+ Orgs and even though package already has a PS in these orgs users aren't assigned to the PS. 
Also, app is not working since users don't have access to these new fields :-(. 
So instead of having customers adding users to PS we want to do this in post install script but its not adding users to the PS :-(. I followed instruction in link; find profile access to object and add users of profile to PS...works in Bus. Org but not Customer.  Any idea?